# Console output keeps crashing

Tags: c++, string, console, iostream, getline

Trying to solve this [Problem](http://ww2.codechef.com/problems/DIRECTI).
I have written the code which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int i,j,n,t;

int main()
{
cin>>t;

while(t--)
{
    vector <string> dr,rd;
    string a,b;
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a.clear(),b.clear();
        getline(cin,a);
        j=a.find(" on ");
        b=a.substr(j,a.size()-1);
        a.resize(j);
        dr.push_back(a);
        rd.push_back(b);
    }

    for(i=0,j=rd.size()-1;i<rd.size();i++,j--)
    {
        cout<<dr[i]<<rd[j]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly, at least on the given example when I run it using file I/O(fstream) but when i use console I/O as is the code given it crashes after reading the second number for test case.

Like this:
2 
4
Begin on Road A
Right on Road B
Right on Road C
Left on Road D *(reads and prints what should be printed until here)*
6 *(reads this and goes to new line)*
*(crashes)* Begin on Old Madras Road 
Left on Domlur Flyover
Left on 100 Feet Road
Right on Sarjapur Road
Right on Hosur Road
Right on Ganapathi Temple Road

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

If you say that your program "crashes", you should also say *how* it crashes
and if possible quote the exact output that shows how it is crashing. Many
people who might be able to help will not bother if they have to work
out what the problem really *is* as well as solve it.

If your question is about a coding problem, like yours, it is also important
to tag your question with the name of the programming language you are
coding in - in your case C++. If you don't, then most C++ programmers who
could help will simply never notice your question. (I have now tagged your
question C++.)

And if you are programming in a compiled language, like C++, it is also
helpful to say what compiler you are using, and what version of that compiler,
- e.g. "GCC 4.7.2", "MS VC++ 2012" - because then programmers can try to
reproduce the problem using the same one. It is quite common for coding
problems to be in some way dependent on the compiler or compiler version being
used.

I have built your program with GCC 4.7.2 and clang 3.2 on Linux and it executes the test
case that you have given with no problems when I enter the input lines from
the console.

This leaves me to speculate what you mean when you say it "crashes", and this
is what I speculate:

I think you may mean that after you enter "6", the program terminates with
an error diagnostic something like:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr
Aborted
```

If I am wrong about that, feel free to stop reading now.

If I am right about that, then the diagnostic is telling you that in your
call `a.substr(j,a.size()-1)`, the index `j` is out of range.

If `j` is out of range at that point, then it must have got out of range as
a result of the preceding line `j=a.find(" on ")`. And that can only mean
that `a.find(" on ")` failed to find `" on "` at any place in `a`.

Look up the documentation of `std::string::find`, e.g. 
[here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)
and read about the returned value:

> If no matches were found, the function returns string::npos.

which is `(size_t)-1`, and is assuredly out of range.

Next, if `a.find(" on ")` is failing, that can only mean that the
preceding line `getline(cin,a)` is failing at that point to read a line from `cin` that
contains `" on "`. And we know that is true! Because you say that the program 
crashes right after it has read "6" and printed the required newline.

So that `getline(cin,a)` must be reading a line from the console *after* the
"6" but *before* "Begin on Old Madras Road". An empty line. And that is what
it would do if you happened to press `[Enter]` just a bit too long when
entering the "6", so that the keyboard buffer contains "6\n\n", or maybe
"6\n\n\n", instead of just "6\n". Your call to `cin.ignore()`, after reading
the integer, will consume only *one* following character, because you are
accepting the default arguments of:

```
std::istream& std::istream::ignore(std::streamsize n = 1, int delim = EOF)
```

As I say, your program works fine for me. But I can make it crash in the
way I described by pressing `[Enter]` either too long when I enter the test
case line-count - either the first time or the second time - or by pressing
`[Enter]` again after I have done so. Either way, I am inputting an empty line
to `getline(cin,a)`.

If I am right so far, then a serious error in your code is that *you are not
checking that `std::string::find()` is successful on an input string and just 
assuming that it is*. Even if I am not right, that is serious error.

You can stop your program from crashing when the user's finger stays too
long on `[Enter]` by ensuring that `cin` ignores *all* the newlines it can
read after `cin>>n`. You must look at the next character, if any,
without extracting it; check if it is a newline, and if it is then extract it
and repeat. Replace `cin.ignore()` with:

```
for (   ;cin.peek() == '\n'; cin.ignore()){}
```

However this will not prevent your program from crashing in the same way if the
user happens to mistakenly enter a route-line that does not contain `" on "`:
try it with "Left On Domlur Flyover".

To fix this bug you must check that `j=a.find(" on ")` is successful and
handle the situation when it is not. Here is complete fix for what I think is the problem, built with GCC 4.7.2
and clang 3.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

int t;

cin>>t;

while(t--)
{
    vector <string> dr,rd;
    string a,b;
    size_t i,j,n;
    cin>>n;
    for (   ;cin.peek() == '\n'; cin.ignore()){}

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a.clear(),b.clear();
        getline(cin,a);
        j=a.find(" on ");
        if (j == string::npos) {
            cout << "Invalid direction. Try again" << endl;
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        b=a.substr(j,a.size()-1);
        a.resize(j);
        dr.push_back(a);
        rd.push_back(b);
    }

    for(i=0,j=rd.size()-1;i<rd.size();i++,j--)
    {
        cout<<dr[i]<<rd[j]<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Notice I have also corrected a couple of minor defects:-

- No need for any global variables. It is good practice to avoid globals
  if possible and to declare variables in the smallest possible scope.
- I have changed the type of `i,j,n` from `int` to `size_t`. Variables
  that used to hold the return value of `some_class::some_method()` or the
  return value of `some_function()`, or are compared with that return value, 
  are best declared with the same type as that return value to avoid bugs and 
  compiler warnings: `string::find()` and `vector::size()` return `size_t`, 
  which is not the same as `int`.

**P.S.** Investigate what goes wrong, either with your original program or
mine, if the user mistakenly enters one of the integer inputs as, say,
"y" or "6y" instead of "6". How could you fix that?